# Where is my saved file on Android?

Tags: android, file

I'm creating a text file like that:

```
private void writeToFile(String data) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("ruta.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

According to Google:

> Note: Your app's internal storage directory is specified by your app's package name in a special location of the Android file system.

I thought that special location was Android/data/com.nameofmyapp
But "ruta.txt" isn't there, just a folder called cache with other things.

Comment: Did you get any exceptions thrown? Do you have the appropriate permissions in the manifest?

Comment: I have permissions and no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

in android you have 2 main places where to save files, "external storage" (into your device filesystem) and "internal storage" (internal private location)

this code writes in your "internal storage"

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

you cannot find files saved into "internal storage" because these files are embedded and encrypted into a private location (inside the apk file).

here you can find details:

> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

what is the best storage? it is hard to define a rule, generally I use external storage for big files or files that can be seen by all, and I use internal storage for small private files

Comment: *app internal storage (inside your apk)* inside your apk, please clarify, that is misleading.

Comment: It is not stored inside the APK - it is stored in an internal, private location.

Comment: Ok, I thought internal storage was phone's memory and external the SD card, so it isn't? I must use external storage for my purpose?

Comment: it is hard to define a rule, generally I use external storage for big files or files that can be seen by all, and I use internal storage for small private files

Answer (score 0):

The default path is /data/data/com.nameofmyapp/

There you have folders for the cache, files, shared Prefs and the libarys. In the app's Files folder will be the saved txt File :)

I don't know what you want to do, but you may use

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to get the exernal storage path, create a Folder there with the name of your app and save your files in this Folder so that users can go to the path easily when they want to save the files on a exernal media

Comment: i don't have /data folder, it's required to be root to see it?

Comment: Yes you need root as long as you save the file at the default app path and not using other methods like external storage paths